# Presence check on python?

Tags: python

Hi im new with python but in my school i was asked to write a code that ask the user to input a word and a sentence with few feature but it must have a presence check (so the user cant just leave the question blank or the word) but i dont know how to put a presence check, also if the word or sentence is left blank the user should be able to re-enter it again. can anyone help me?

Comment: What about `Word_To_Find in UserSen`? Furthermore in Python variables usually are lowercase, my eyes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop as long as `UserSen` is empty:

```
UserSen = input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation: ").lower()   
while len(UserSen) == 0:
    UserSen = input("Please type in a sentence without punctuation: ").lower() 

UserSen = UserSen.split()
```

Comment: It may raise error in Python 2.7 if user enter non-string value like `int`, `float` (as `len` is not supported on them)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri he used `input` so I presumed python 3. You can always associate `input = raw_input; range = xrange` after version check

Comment: Done! thank you so much i really appreciate the instan help so now i can carry on with my task